# Python float __setformat__?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

I have a problem, where i need to get a float correct upto 18 decimal places.
When i use default float(number), it gives me 12 decimal places only.

Then i did dir(float)

```
    ['__abs__', '__add__', '__class__', '__coerce__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__divmod__', '__doc__',
 '__eq__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getformat__',
 '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__int__', '__le__', '__long__', '__lt__', '__m
od__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '
__rdiv__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rmod__', '_
_rmul__', '__rpow__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__setattr__', '__setformat__', '__sizeof__', '__s
tr__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', 'as_integer_ratio', 'conjugate', '
fromhex', 'hex', 'imag', 'is_integer', 'real']
```

There is something called __setformat__ in that block. What is its use? and how to use it for floating point precision setting?

I am using python 2.7.5 x64.

Comment: Have you tried: `help(float.__setformat__)`?

Comment: I don't think floats *have* 18 decimal places of accuracy. You may want to use a `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at IEEE 754, in order to understand that a float does not have a fixed number of decimals as it is stored as a signum, a mantissa and an exponent, with special configurations for NaN, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only of use to the Python test suite; `help(float.__setformat__)` prints:

> `float.__setformat__(typestr, fmt) -> None`
>
> You probably don't want to use this function.  It exists mainly to be
>   used in Python's test suite.
>
> *typestr* must be `'double'` or `'float'`.  *fmt* must be one of `'unknown'`,
>   `'IEEE, big-endian'` or `'IEEE, little-endian'`, and in addition can only be
>   one of the latter two if it appears to match the underlying C reality.
>
> Overrides the automatic determination of C-level floating point type.
>   This affects how floats are converted to and from binary strings.

There is a `float.__getformat__()` as well, the getter method for the same information, same purpose.

See the [`float` test suite](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/test/test_float.py) for more details on its use.

Use the [`decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) to get more accurate decimal calculations, but do check out [`sys.float_info`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) for details on how accurate floats are on your platform. My 64bit Mac OS X system can only manage 15 digits, for example.

Comment: can you tell me a way to get 18 or more decimal places of accuracy?

Comment: @falloutx Perhaps you're looking for the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module

Answer (score 5):

It astonishes me how people on this forum go out of their way to avoid seeing the real question, which is, admittedly, very poorly worded by someone who is obviously very new to python.  It's a good newbie question, so I'll make things explicit.

Clearly, `__setformat__` is useless for the desired purpose of "falloutx".  Typing:

```
>>> help(float.__setformat__)
```

will give anyone who needs an explanation an answer, which no newbie could reasonably be interested in.

The implicit query is, nevertheless valid.

If I do this:

```
>>> from math import pi
>>> print pi
3.14159265359
```

I see only twelve decimal places.  Python uses double precision, so I can do this:

```
>>> print "{:.16}".format(pi)
3.1415926535897931
```

This is correct except for the trailing '1' which should be a '2'.  That is
because double precision can only represent about 16 significant digits, and the integral '3' counts as one significant digit.

So to answer the real question:
Internally, you have 16 significant digits.  That means for a value 'v' in the range -1.0 < v < 1.0, the best you can display is 16 decimal places.  If your value has an integral component, that will reduce available decimal precision, possibly eliminating it altogether for very large values.

To see the full precision, use string formatting as above.

A cosmetic problem can arise, however:

```
>>> print "{:.16f}".format(1.0)
1.0000000000000000
```

You can do this:

```
>>> print "{:.16f}".format(1.0).rstrip('0')
1.
```

Another query:
[Change default float print format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264828/change-default-float-print-format) has some interesting approaches to this problem.  So, for example, if the wordiness of the print statement bothers you, and you really would like to see at least one digit of decimal precision, you can do this:

```
>>> class newfloat(float):
...   precision=4
...   def __str__(self):
...     s="{{:.{0}f}}".format(self.precision)
...     s=s.format(self)
...     if s.endswith('0'): s=s.rstrip('0')+'0'
...     return s
... 
>>> f=newfloat(pi)
>>> g=newfloat(1.0)
>>> print f,g
3.1416 1.0
>>> newfloat.precision=2
>>> print f,g
3.14 1.0
```

If you are doing a lot of string formatting using the .format construct, you can achieve the same result by defining a class, as above but naming it, say,
'_'.  Then you do this:

```
>>> "A {0} string with {1} custom float format {2}".format(*map(_,(1,2,pi)))
'A 1.0 string with 2.0 custom float format 3.14'
```