# How to print list of lists with values having 3 decimal numbers?

Tags: list, python-2.7, decimal

```
a = [[1.0993455308580886, 1.9814814814814814, 1.2331369355392543, 1.646283618833137, 2.2736098709332486, 1.50035992597825]]
```

I have the list of lists above. How can i print it in order to have the number printed with 3 decimal numbers. I want this:

```
b = [[1.099, 1.981, 1.233, 1.646, 2.273, 1.500]]
```

Is there a way so that i can force all float numbers in my code to have 3 decimal numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default float print format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264828/change-default-float-print-format)

Comment: @RicardoCruz there is no answer for lists there :/

Comment: when you do `print(obj)`, the `print` function will call either `obj.__str__()` or `obj.__repr__()`, if the first is not implemented. In the case of `list`, the list will then call the respective functions for each element. In your case, `float.__str__()` will be called. There is no way to change this globally, but you can implement your own print function for your lists in an ad-hoc basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a dup of [Change default float print format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264828/change-default-float-print-format).

Long story short: you cannot change it globally. But you can write a function such that

```
return [[round(n, 3) for n in a[0]]]
```

or

```
return [['%.3f' % n for n in a[0]]]
```

Creating lists like this is called list comprehension. Alternatively, you can also use `map`:

```
return [map(lambda n: '%.3f' % n, a[0])]
```

But usually Python developers prefer list comprehension.

Comment: can you explain to me how does return [['%.3f' % n for n in a[0]]], works and how can i write it in more than one line, to be more readable to me?

Comment: You can write it as: `l = []; for n in a[0]: l.append('%.3f' % n)` (breaking lines as necessary). The problem is that it is much **slower**. It is much faster to use list comprehension (`l = [element for element in list]`) or `map`. These are python specific tricks so that the code can be optimized and run at C-speed.

Comment: Thank you it helped a lot :)