# Printing the output rounded to 3 decimals in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I got a SymPy matrix `M`

```
In [1]: from sympy import *
In [2]: M = 1/10**6 * Matrix(([1, 10, 100], [1000, 10000, 100000]))
In [3]: M
Out[3]: 
Matrix([
[1.0e-6, 1.0e-5, 0.0001],
[ 0.001,   0.01,    0.1]])
```

I want to print the output rounded to 3 decimals, as follows:

```
In [3]: M
Out[3]: 
Matrix([
[ 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
[ 0.001, 0.010, 0.100]])
```

In normal Python, I would go like this:

```
In [5]: '{:.3f}'.format(1/10**6)
Out[5]: '0.000'
```

But how to do in a SymPy matrix?

Moreover, a more general case would be an expression containing also Symbols

```
x = symbols('x')
M = 1/10**6 * Matrix(([1, 10*x, 100], [1000, 10000*x, 100000]))
```

The preferred output is

```
In [3]: M
Out[3]: 
Matrix([
[ 0.000, 0.000*x, 0.000],
[ 0.001, 0.010*x, 0.100]])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To round every number in an expression, use the following function

```
def round_expr(expr, num_digits):
    return expr.xreplace({n : round(n, num_digits) for n in expr.atoms(Number)})
```

It can be applied to any SymPy expression, including matrices.

```
x = symbols('x')
M = 1/10**6 * Matrix(([1, 10*x, 100], [1000, 10000*x, 100000]))
round_expr(M, 3)
```

yields

```
Matrix([
[  0.0,      0, 0.0],
[0.001, 0.01*x, 0.1]])
```

---

For numeric matrices, the following is simpler and preserves trailing zeros:

```
>>> M.applyfunc(lambda x: Symbol('{:.3f}'.format(x)))
Matrix([
[0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
[0.001, 0.010, 0.100]])
```

Here, `applyfunc` applies the given function to each entry of M. A natural thing to try would be `lambda x: '{:.3f}'.format(x)` but SymPy matrices aren't really meant to hold strings: the strings get parsed back into numbers and the trailing zeros get dropped, resulting in

```
Matrix([
[  0.0,  0.0, 0.0],
[0.001, 0.01, 0.1]])
```

So I wrap each string in `Symbol`, thus making a new symbol out of it. Symbols can appear in matrices, and they printed as their names, in this case the names are "0.000" and so on.

Comment: Thanks! As I want to work on with `M`, your solution `lambda x: '{:.3f}'.format(x)` is perfectly fine for me.

Comment: In that case, you really just wanted to `round` the numbers, which is done with `M.applyfunc(lambda x: round(x, 3))`

Comment: However, this won't work for `x = symbols('x')` and `M = 1/10**6 * Matrix(([1, 10*x, 100], [1000, 10000*x, 100000]))`, throwing `TypeError: type Mul doesn't define __round__ method`. But that case was not included in my question... @if.... I wonder if you have a solution for that too? I will edit the question...

Comment: I tried using the lambda expression, and it threw this error: `TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Zero.__format__`

Answer (score 3):

I needed to improve these 2 solutions (Space47 already improved the accepted solution) because my numbers were very big, and Sympy just send "123456789.123 x"

```
def printM(expr, num_digits):
     return expr.xreplace({n.evalf() : n if type(n)==int else Float(n, num_digits) for n in expr.atoms(Number)})
```

so "123456789.123 x" will be displayed 1.23 * 10^8
and the function does NOT change representation of integers (previously, "1" was replaced by "1.0")

Answer (score 2):

A little bit old, but I used some time to find this today and needed some adjustment. My solution to the exact same question is as a previous answer (user6655984) but with evalf():

```
def printM(expr, num_digits):
    return expr.xreplace({n.evalf() : round(n, num_digits) for n in expr.atoms(Number)})
```

Then e.g. sqrt(13) is still sqrt(13) and not a numeric value. (Otherwise it is converted to a numeric value **after** the round and thus having more digits than num_digits.  At least in Sympy 1.3 at Python 3.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

I had some code with many instructions of the form `print('some string', some_sympy_expression)`.
So I used [the function by 2diabolos.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60284977/2707864) (named as `round_expr`), defined function below, and replaced every `print` with `print_my`.

```
def print_my(*args, **kwargs):
    end_my = kwargs['end'] if 'end' in kwargs else '\n'
    sep_my = kwargs['sep'] if 'sep' in kwargs else ' '
    for arg in args:
        if (type(arg)==str):
            print(arg, end=sep_my)
        else:
            print(round_expr(arg, 3), end=sep_my)
    print(end=end_my)
    return
```

I didn't take the time to check if there are other use cases that require some modification for this to work, or even others which cannot be made to work with this approach.