# Rounding coefficients of a symbolic expression in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm currently trying to calculate a negative group delay of analog filters by using symbolic calculations in Python. The problem that I'm currently trying to resolve is to get rid of some very small imaginary coefficients.

For example, consider fraction with such numerator (imaginary parts are bolded):

(-1.705768*w^18 + 14.702976409432*w^16 + **1.06581410364015e-14*I*w^15** - 28.7694094371724*w^14 - **9.94759830064144e-14*I*w^13** + 59.0191623753299*w^12 + **5.6843418860808e-14*I*w^11** + 24.7015297857594*w^10 - **1.13686837721616e-13*I*w^9** - 549.093511217598*w^8 - **5.6843418860808e-14*I*w^7** + 1345.40434657845*w^6 + **2.27373675443232e-13*I*w^5** - 1594.14046181284*w^4 - **1.13686837721616e-13*I*w^3** + 980.58940367608*w^2 - 254.8428594382)

Is there any way to automatically round those small coefficients, so they would be equal 0 (in general any negligligible values)? Or at least, can I somehow filter imaginary values out? I've tried to use re(given_fraction), but it couldn't return anything. Also standard rounding function can't cope with symbolic expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The rounding part was already addressed in [Printing the output rounded to 3 decimals in SymPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491577/printing-the-output-rounded-to-3-decimals-in-sympy) so I won't repeat my answer there, focusing instead of dropping imaginary parts of coefficients.

#### Method 1

You can simply do `re(expr)` where expr is your expression. But for this to work, w must be known to be a real variable; otherwise there is no way for SymPy to tell what the real part of `(3+4*I)*w` is. (SymPy symbols are assumed to be complex unless stated otherwise.) This will do the job:

```
w = symbols('w', real=True)
expr = # your formula
expr = re(expr)
```

#### Method 2

If for some reason you can't do the above... another, somewhat intrusive, way to drop the imaginary part of *everything* is to replace I with 0:

```
expr = expr.xreplace({I: 0})
```

This assumes the expression is already in the expanded form (as shown), so there is no `(3+4*I)**2`, for example; otherwise the result would be wrong.

#### Method 3

A more robust approach than 2, but specialized to polynomials:

```
expr = Poly([re(c) for c in Poly(expr, w).all_coeffs()], w).as_expr()
```

Here the expression is first turned into a polynomial in `w` (which is possible in your example, since it has a polynomial form). Then the real part of each coefficient is taken, and a polynomial is rebuilt from them. The final part `as_expr()` returns it back to expression form, if desired.

Either way, the output for your expression:

```
-1.705768*w**18 + 14.702976409432*w**16 - 28.7694094371724*w**14 + 59.0191623753299*w**12 + 24.7015297857594*w**10 - 549.093511217598*w**8 + 1345.40434657845*w**6 - 1594.14046181284*w**4 + 980.58940367608*w**2 - 254.8428594382
```