# Setting a default float format for numpy arrays and scalars alike

Tags: python, numpy, string-formatting

With:

```
sci_format = ":.3e"
numpyp.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':sci_format})
```

every float in a numpy array is displayed with the sci_format format.

I'd like to do the same for scalars so that

```
print('g equals ',2234.23)
```

displays

```
g equals 2.234e3
```

without the need to add the formatting string for each print statement. Can it be achieved ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default float print format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264828/change-default-float-print-format)

Comment: Not really since all the solutions proposed requires that you add some parameter or option to the print() statement.

Comment: Default display is set by class.  `numpy` formatting is different from floats, even if the array has a float dtype   I was going to type 'contains floats', but here that has the wrong implications.